# x-stor(e)y or x-floor or x-level house/building?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, british-english

Which is the correct for British English? I need the correct for both a separate house and an apartment building, if this makes difference. I can't find any concrete answer online.

Comment: a x-storey building/house.

Comment: @graffito but on the z-th floor yes?

Comment: Yes. To refer to a specific floor: you will say "my office is on the fifth floor".

Comment: Just beware Americans and British count floors differently, British have "Ground floor, 1st floor, 2nd floor..." whereas Americans (if memory serves) *start* at 1st floor for "ground" or "street" level and count up from there.

Comment: Also note that some split-level homes aren't considered to be multi-storey.

Comment: Following Jim's comment, Wikipedia describes a tri-level home which has two storeys but three levels. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-level_home

Comment: I hope you mean 5-storey building, and not something with the actual letter x in there.

Answer (score 1):

### 2-storey, 3-storey house; 80-floor skyscraper

Either "-storey" or "-floor" sounds natural in UK English.

"-storey" is particularly used for small numbers (such as 2 or 3), and for long term living accommodation (i.e. a block of flats/apartments).

"-floor" is most often used for large numbers, especially of an office building, hotel, or with the word "skyscraper".

"-level" is less common in general, except when it is describing something that would normally be expected to have only one storey/floor/level, but in this unusual case has two or more, such as a "2-level apartment". Indeed, it is more likely to be called a "split-level apartment", to emphasise the unusual splitting of an abode.

Incidentally the UK spelling is "storey" while the US spelling is "story". In both, the plural is "stories".

> "Residents living in the shadow of Grenfell Tower have said they fear for their health after an independent study found cancer-causing chemicals near to the 24-storey block, which was destroyed by fire in 2017."

Source: [The Guardian, 2019](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2019/mar/28/grenfell-tenants-voice-health-fears-in-wake-of-contamination-report)

> They moved from a bungalow to a 3-storey house when they got married.

### First floor

US and Canada count stories from 1 at the ground floor.

UK and Europe in general count stories (effectively) from 0 at the ground floor, although typically they name the ground floor just "Ground" rather than explicitly level 0. The first floor, in UK/Europe, is the floor immediately above the ground floor.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked, which was how to describe a building with a certain number of floors.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on context. But typically in British English you would say:

> I am building a five story house

or

> My room is on the fifth floor

But 'level' tends to be more of an American English usage rather than British English.  However, 99.99% of English speakers would understand the meaning of its usage in a sentence.

Comment: As noted in a comment under the Q., in a 5-storey British house, the stories would be "Ground, 1st, 2nd, 3rd & 4th" - so it would be difficult to have your room "on the fifth floor"!  "My room is on the **top** floor" would also be more likely than "Xth floor".